# What is the meaning of 「あれほど」?

Tags: words, meaning

Here is the full sentence I have found:

> あんた **あれほど**ボクシングをきらっていたのに
>   どうして急に本気でやる気になったの?

Does it mean 'me'?

Comment: Isn't it **あれ**ほど?

Comment: Yes, it is あれほど.

Comment: I don't have time to do a full answer, but あれほど means "so much" or "to such an extent". Best I can tell, this sentence says, "Given that you used to hate boxing **so much**, why have you suddenly become so seriously motivated [to box]?"

Comment: I am agreeing with @Eric on this one

Comment: I am agreeing with @TheWanderingCoder agreeing with Eric . But it is not "so much". It is "this（あれ） much（ほど）".

Comment: I would argue, **THAT** much. これ > this, それ AND あれ > that (albeit different degrees).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @Eric says,

> あれほど means "so much" or "to such an extent". Best I can tell, this sentence says, "Given that you used to hate boxing so much, why have you suddenly become so seriously motivated [to box]?"

However, as @oldergod mentions, `あれほど` would mean close "to such an extent", or "that much" rather than "so much".

> You hated boxing **`that much`**, what suddenly made you become so motivated [to box]?"